# Missing indices: missing a few indices from a few weeks ago, is it possible to get those into ElasticSearch without duplicates?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, amazon-cloudwatch

I am quite new to ElasticSearch (ELK Stack) and am having some issues with missing indices. I am using the cloudwatch-input plugin for logstash to get logs from CloudWatch into ElasticSearch. I am running logstash as a container on an ec2 instance. It is currently getting logs in real time from CloudWatch and outputting them to ElasticSearch, that is working as expected.

However, we have some missing data from a few weeks ago - we are missing 3 consecutive indices in ElasticSearch that cover almost 1 month worth of data. (screenshot below)

Is it possible to move just the missing data (that is present in CloudWatch still) into elasticsearch without causing duplicates? What is the easiest/best way to accomplish this?

Missing indices (indexed by week; missing 10, 11, 12):
[Current Indices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6bof.png)

Relevant inputs:

```
cloudwatch_logs {
    log_group => [
      "/ecs/prod"
    ]
    region => "us-west-2"
    type => "api-prod"
    start_position => "end"
    interval => 10
 }

 cloudwatch_logs {
    log_group => [
      "/ecs/prod-api"
    ]
    region => "us-west-2"
    type => "api-prod"
    start_position => "end"
    interval => 10
 }
```

I've tried updating the inputs for the two cloudwatch log groups by setting

```
start_position => "beginning"
```

Which didn't do anything since our .sincedb-* entry is still there, and also adding

```
start_position => "beginning"
ignore_older => 0
```

actually caused my logstash container to be in a crash loop, which I was able to resolve by doing a docker copy to pull the modified config file, updating then copying back into the container.

I believe I can add

```
sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
```

so that the input does not look at the .sincedb for the last log added, but I am afraid that this will cause duplicates, or some other issues I am not aware of yet. I am also understanding that it is possible to delete the entries in .sincedb so that logstash starts at the beginning of the log, but I still have the concerns about duplicating data.

Please let me know if I can provide any other helpful information. Thank you in advance!

UPDATE:
I set the CloudWatch inputs to

```
start_position => "beginning"
sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
```

And restarted logstash. This ended up pulling missing logs, but not from the specific time ranges / indices I was looking for

Comment: In filebeat setting ignore_older to zero disables age-based filtering. In a logstash file input it causes the input to ignore any file more than zero seconds old, which is usually all of them.

Comment: @Badger thank you for the clarification - that part wasn't super clear in the docs, and I have seen folks use it a few different ways (not sure if successfully)